# Most upvoted and viewed questions

Tags: feature-request

Is there any way to see the list of the most upvoted and the most viewed questions in this day/week/month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most views (all-time) ... someone on Mathoverflow showed how to do it.  Here is the [result](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/166948/most-views) for math.se

Comment: The query was mentioned on MO in [this comment](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/753/history-of-mathoverflow#comment6788_1486).

Comment: [now with links to questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/167049/questions-with-most-views)

Comment: And a further little improvement: [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/167951/questions-with-most-views-including-links-to-post-and-number-of-vies) shows a link as well as number of views for each question listed there.

Answer (score 9):

There *is* this feature already -- it's called `greatest-hits` and it isn't linked anywhere. I know, it's frustrating!

For Math, you can see this list of questions by adding `/greatest-hits` to the questions URL. Basically, just click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) and you should see the page.

This is a dynamic list of the top 1000 questions on your site, with views and votes getting weighted into the placement.

Comment: Thanks but can we categorize them daily?

Comment: Hmmm. I don't think so, but I don't think you can categorize by daily *anywhere*. And I don't think that will be a function that realistically could happen. Sorry! But hey -- all-time greatest hits is still better than none at all.

Comment: Many (all?) of these "greatest hits" likely got most of their votes from rubbernecking traffic perusing the Hot Questions List. As such. that ranking does not really represent the opinion of the MSE community. Is there any way to exclude the rubbernecking votes, e.g. count only votes from MSE users with rep over a certain threshhold? Perhaps there is a query that already does that.