# Most Downvoted Questions

Tags: feature-request

Does there exist any way to see the most downvoted questions in this day/week/month/year/of all time on here?  I tried doing a search for "most downvoted" and found [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/most-upvoted-and-viewed-questions), which suggests the "dual" exists.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I found what I was looking for there Qiaochu!

Comment: @Qiaochu Can one do similarly for this meta site?

Comment: You mean besides [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/11300/doug-spoonwood?tab=questions)?? I jest... :)

Comment: I don't like the downvote sistem who are children? You can always downvote a silly question, but it wont make a great Mathematician not even a mean mathematician but a mathematician mean!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) handles a lot of such queries.
2. There is a particular post for ["Posts with most upvotes, downvotes, total votes, highest and lowest total score"](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/60848/posts-with-most-upvotes-downvotes-total-votes-highest-and-lowest-total-score). I don't use the data explorer enough to know *how*, but I'm fairly sure you can place time limits on the queries.

Comment: In this case, I clicked on "fork query" here: http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/50634/recent-unpopular-questions, and then changed "month -1" to "month -60", which I think edits the code so that it goes back further than the (mathematics) site has existed for.

Answer (score 6):

You can sort the "questions"
 page  by votes and go to the last page:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?page=753&sort=votes

This only works for "all time" though.