# Searching questions by number of views

Tags: support, search

There is a way to see the most viewed/upvoted questions on the site:

[Most upvoted and viewed questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/most-upvoted-and-viewed-questions)

However, what if we on the other hand wanted to find the "bottom sludge" of all the questions; the least viewed ones?

Is there a way to search by number of views?

Comment: This sounds like an issue for the [main meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search using `views` operator: for example, [views:0-10](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A0-10).

After clicking, you will see "Advanced Search Tips" in the right column; these describe other search functions available at SE.

Comment: Awesome. But I guess it's not completely accurate?

Comment: @semigroupsareawesome It reflects the number of views, as recorded in the site's database. The latter is determined in a [fairly complicated way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728). Some numbers are very low. I think that migrated questions do not keep the number of views they had on the original site.